# What does the term 'fatal conceit' mean in this instance?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [Paul Ryan Is 'Not A Fan' Of Romneycare And Compared It To Obamacare](http://www.businessinsider.com/paul-ryan-hammered-romneycare-before-vp-pick-2012-8):

> They see how this idea of having the government be the sole, single
>   regulator of health insurance, defining what kind of health insurance
>   you can have, and then the individual mandate, it is a fatal conceit.

I have tried to understand the meaning, but I could not grasp it all. I don't understand the usage of "conceit" here. Someone please re-write this sentence so it's simpler to understand.

Comment: That sounds like a quote and not something someone would write. It strings two different, albeit related thoughts into a single sentence.  But I would say that *conceit* should be interpreted as *An extravagant, fanciful, and elaborate construction or structure*.  See [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conceit)

Comment: It seems to be a misuse of the usual meaning of "fatal conceit".

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like the kind of sentence people say but wouldn’t write.  A paraphrase would be (missing out some of the more flowery excrescences):

> They see that it is a fatal conceit to have the government as the sole health care regulator together with the individual mandate.

A word on a couple of the phrases here.

- *Fatal conceit* means something like *deadly pride* or *lethal hubris*, I think.  However, another meaning of *conceit* is *concept*, so that the phrase could mean *lethal concept/idea*—though I doubt that this is what’s meant.
- *Individual mandate* means a mandate (order) on the individual to do something, in this case, from memory, to purchase health insurance.

The difficulty with the quoted version is that the speaker (rather than writer, I assume) begins a lengthy description (a participial phrase modifying a participial phrase containing two partially redundant adjectives).  They then tack on another phrase (*and then the individual mandate*), which it is hard to integrate into the growing sentence (what, for instance, is the elided verb meant to be?).  Finally, they reach *it is a fatal conceit*.  This forces you to interpret everything that has gone before as a hanging topic (e.g.: ***The economy, it**’s central to the debate*).  But the result feels zeugmatic: *it is* is singular, but *having the government* and *the individual mandate* sound like separate things, so we expect a plural.

In sum, I sort of feel you deserve congratulations for not quite understanding the original.

Comment: A fluent speaker might indeed find fault with the grammar, but the semantics are straightforward. You're right about this sounding spoken rather than written - in fact, in speech it's common to "break" the grammatical rules we'd find in writing.

Answer (score 4):

NOAD mentions that one meaning of conceit is *a fanciful notion*.  Candidate Ryan was essentially stating his position that government-run health care (with government as the sole, single regulator of health insurance, along with individual mandates) was *doomed to fail*.